# How to access actual numbers within a series[float] in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Ok so what I'm trying to achieve sounds fairly simple: look back on the past weekly highs and lows (so every Sunday at 8pm EST), and chart those levels as horizontal lines. I want to do this for the past 12 weeks or so

However when I try to do this, I can't seem to grab just the actual values from the series object. Here's my code so far, trying to draw just one of the levels:

```
allLows = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", low)
allHighs = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high)

h = allHighs[1]
l = allLows[1]

plot(h, "High (sell zone)", color.red)
plot(l, "Low (buy zone)", color.green)
```

Here's the image I get:

[image]

And here's something closer to what I actually want (drew these manually):

[image]

Ideally I'd like to just grab the actual values in the `allHighs` and `allLows` series and just plot these, but for the life of me can't figure out how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 24)

interval = input("W")

new_interval = change(time(interval)) != 0

var float hh = na
var int hh_index = na
var float ll = na
var int ll_index = na

if new_interval
    line.new(x1 = hh_index, y1 = hh, x2 = hh_index + 1, y2 = hh, color = color.red, extend = extend.right)
    line.new(x1 = ll_index, y1 = ll, x2 = ll_index + 1, y2 = ll, color = color.green, extend = extend.right)
    hh := high
    ll := low
    hh_index := bar_index
    ll_index := bar_index
else
    if high > hh
        hh := high
        hh_index := bar_index
    if low < ll
        ll := low
        ll_index := bar_index
```

Note the `max_lines_count`. It will limit how many historical lines. There are a number of other ways it could be done. For easier referencing of the values or for more control of the lines use var arrays to store the values as well as var line arrays.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was overcomplicating it by trying to use `security`

Comment: I made sure to credit you on tradingview btw @rumpypumpydumpy

Comment: Thanks, that's nice of you. You could use security to obtain the price values, but you would have had to do it this way to obtain the right bar_index to position the start of the line anyway.